# Creating UIImage with per-pixel alpha from GL buffer

Tags: iphone, opengl, uiimage, alpha

I'm trying to take my gl buffer and turn it into a UIImage while retaining the per-pixel alpha within that gl buffer.  It doesn't seem to work, as the result I'm getting is the buffer w/o alpha.  Can anyone help?  I feel like I must be missing a few key steps somewhere.  I would really love any advice on this.

Basically I do:

```
//Read Pixels from OpenGL
glReadPixels(0, 0, miDrawBufferWidth, miDrawBufferHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

//Make data provider with data.
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer, len, NULL);

//Configure image
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(miDrawBufferWidth, miDrawBufferHeight, 8, 32, (4 * miDrawBufferWidth), colorSpaceRef, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault, provider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

// use device's orientation's width/height to determine context dimensions (and consequently resulting image's dimensions)
uint32* pixels = (uint32 *) IQ_NEW(kHeapGfx, "snapshot_pixels") GLubyte[len];

// use kCGImageAlphaLast? :-/
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, iRotatedWidth, iRotatedHeight, 8, (4 * iRotatedWidth), CGImageGetColorSpace(iref), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);


CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, miDrawBufferWidth, miDrawBufferHeight), iref);
UIImage *outputImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)];

//cleanup
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
CGImageRelease(iref);
CGContextRelease(context);

return outputImage;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes!  Luckily apparently someone has solved this exact problem here: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/23525-cgimagecreate-alpha.html

It boiled down to an extra kCGImageAlphaLast flag being passed into the CGImageCreate to incorporate the alpha (along with the kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault flag). :)